# How to identify USB device is a mass storage device on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, usb-drive, iokit

How to identify a device connected on USB port is a mass storage device with the help of Mac OSX IO Kit library? Lets an example USB keyboard and USB flash drive is connected on Mac OSX system. How can i differentiate ONLY the mass storage USB device?

Comment: The IOKit programming guide will tell you. IOKit is very typically a set and get key value game. There are types of devices in IOKit. Start reading and start looking at the headers. It wil be surprisingly easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the IOService node (IOMedia object) corresponding to a *specific* disk using the Disk Arbitration framework's [`DADiskCopyIOMedia` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DiskArbitration/Reference/DADisk_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DADiskCopyIOMedia). You can walk up the IOService tree to your IOUSBInterface/IOUSBDevice from there.

Alternatively, you can use I/O Kit matching to find all USB mass storage or USB attached SCSI (UAS) nodes in the system by their IOKit classes. Similarly for keyboards (they are part of the I/O Kit's HID family).

I suggest taking a look at the IOService tree of your system in IORegistryExplorer.

Comment: Able to detect all USB connected on the system with I/O Kit matching i.e.  matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName). But not exactly sure how to filter out only to find Mass storage USB type. I tried adding sub device class to match dict as kUSBMassStorageRBCSubClass but not getting expected output. <br/> <code>long usbSubDeviceClass = kUSBMassStorageRBCSubClass;<br/>
<code> numberRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &usbSubDeviceClass);
    CFDictionarySetValue( matchingDict, CFSTR(kUSBDeviceSubClass),
                         numberRef);

Comment: `IOUSBMassStorageClass` is the driver class name for USB mass storage interfaces and devices, `IOUSBAttachedSCSI` is the one for UAS. They both act as clients to IOUSBInterface and IOUSBDevice nubs, as far as I'm aware. They also both generate a SCSI device tree below them.